# Static file not serving in Node.js

Tags: node.js, static-files

I am new in programming and face static file serving problem. I followed my tutor properly but still face the problem. This is the server file named app.js from where I want to serve the js file named index.js  in the static directory

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use('/static' , express.static('static'));

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('This is a page of website');
})

app.listen(3000 , ()=>{
    console.log(`The application is running at port ${port}`)
})
```

And I made a directory named static in which I made a file index.js with some js contents.
The tutor then runs the terminal with node ./app.js and in the browser, he searches for the URL as localhost/static/index.js  and he was served with the js file as a static file but for me, it shows the site can't be reached. Considering there is no issue in my node.js processing.

Comment: Replace the line `app.use('/static' , express.static('static'));` with this `app.use('/static' , express.static(__dirname + '/static'));`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was the URL search. As you know that for localhost if you are running the server at port 80 it does not require writing the port. But since I used port 3000 and I do not mention the port in the URL that is why it shows me the site cant be reached and my tutor was using port 80 and me 3000.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue could be that you forgot to add the port to the URL. Your server is listening on port 3000, so you need to search for 'http://localhost:3000/static/index.js'.

Answer (score 0):

one more solution is it here. If the name of the Html file inside the public folder is different from index.html so this is also not work. so first set folder name index.html and then connect your index.js folder to html file ,then run server.you are definitely gets the results .

i am also a psuedo programmer if any mistakes please forgive me.
thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).